# Highstock update y scale on zoom

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstock chart with `rangeSlider` enabled, X is a timeseries, and Y is a relative value (from 0

I would like the relative scale of entries to update based on the first displayed value of the displayed data.

Is this an existing option in highcharts? Or can this be programmed?

Here's an example:

https://www.easy.bnpparibas.fr/professionnel-professionnel/fundsheet/actions/bnp-paribas-easy-sp-500-ucits-etf-eur-c-c-fr0011550185/?tab=perf

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution out of the box through the API:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    compare: 'percent',
    compareBase: 0,
    compareStart: true,
  }
}
```

Everything's in HC API :-D

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own rules for `rangeSelector.buttons`. Here is an example code, showing one month range from the minimum value of the axis.

```
rangeSelector: {
  buttons: [{
    text: '1m',
    events: {
      click: () => {
        const xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
         oneMonth = xAxis.min + 86400000 * 31;
        xAxis.setExtremes(xAxis.min, oneMonth);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }]
},
```

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttons

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

**Demo**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/k3tsa5u1/